# Markdown files are greyed out in Files

Tags: ios, finder, file-sharing

I have markdown files synced on Google Drive, and I already installed a markdown editor which read `.md` files. When the files are local, the editor reads them fine, but when they are in Google Drive folder they are greyed out.

How can I edit the markdown files stored on Google Drive?

## Background

1. The web browser and desktop client of Google Drive both work fine. The problem is certainly with iOS.
2. Other similar problems on the internet were related to PDF files and it worked by installing apps that read the `.pdf` extension, but for me, I already have a markdown editor that reads `.md` extensions.

Comment: Are they greyed out in the Google Drive folder synced to your machine? Or ar they greyed out in the Google Drive interface in your webbrowser? Also, did you search your exact question on the internet? What did you find? Any things that seemed helpful but were not working out? Please include your prior research in your question.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I updated the question

Comment: You mentioned iOS once. Is this problem happening on an iDevice?

Comment: @IconDaemon Yes. An iPhone.